# Dataframe count in Statsmodels OLS formula

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I'm trying to do a linear regression to predict the count of a dataframe based on the count of another dataframe. I am using statsmodels. I have tried the following:

```
X = df1.count()
Y = df2.count()

from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
fit = ols(Y ~ X, data=kak).fit() 
fit.summary()
```

Using the X and Y variables in the OLS formula is not allowed and I have no idea what to fill in at the `data=` keyword argument. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Has any answer below solved your problem? If so, you might want to accept it using the big checkbox beside it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have to 1D arrays `X` and `Y`:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(100)
Y = 2*X + 5
```

Then you can run a linear regression using the line below. There are two important things:

1. The first argument to `ols` is a `str` containing a formula. `"Y ~ X"` and not `Y ~ X` (note the double quotes).
2. The second argument `data` can be any Python object as long as it has keys `data["X"]`  and `data["Y"]`. I wrote a `dict` here, but it would also work with a `DataFrame`. It basically allows `statsmodels` to understand who are `X` and `Y` in the formula you gave to it.

```py
ols("Y ~ X", {"X": X, "Y": Y}).fit().summary()
```

Output:

```
                            OLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      Y   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 1.916e+33
Date:                Fri, 21 May 2021   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        14:01:48   Log-Likelihood:                 3055.1
No. Observations:                 100   AIC:                            -6106.
Df Residuals:                      98   BIC:                            -6101.
Df Model:                           1
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      5.0000   2.62e-15   1.91e+15      0.000       5.000       5.000
X              2.0000   4.57e-17   4.38e+16      0.000       2.000       2.000
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                      220.067   Durbin-Watson:                   0.015
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):                9.816
Skew:                           0.159   Prob(JB):                      0.00739
Kurtosis:                       1.498   Cond. No.                         114.
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```